# How to refresh hidden field value using jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();                                
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

            $('#latitude').val(latitude);
            $('#longitude').val(longitude);
        }
```

latitude and longitude both are hidden elements into form. Both elements have values which i can see using inspect element. But values not display in ajax post form data serialization.

```
$.ajax({
                        url: workAreas,
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType : 'json',
                        data:  $('#workAreaFormMain').serialize(),
                        async: true,
                        success: function(data)
                        {  

                        }                    
                    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You must include a name as well as an id for a form element to be included in the form serialization:

```
<input id="latitude" type="hidden" value="1" name="latitude" />
```

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/u9xvv798/)**

Reference:  https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

> Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Values from checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox") are included only if they are checked. Data from file select elements is not serialized.